# tuple index out of range in scatter plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to scatter plot a two column data which looks the following (with print)

```
0     0.195871-0.008693j  0.117586+0.001306j
1     0.219024+0.003791j  0.132911-0.007069j
2     0.271063-0.009686j -0.135223+0.007258j
3     0.279217-0.010561j  0.174209-0.004157j
4     0.194862+0.017081j  0.108965+0.007829j
...                  ...                 ...
9994  0.398795+0.035182j -0.068538+0.017619j
9995  0.540517+0.059227j -0.250704+0.027940j
9996  0.218166-0.010739j  0.131059-0.008267j
9997  0.285605+0.035444j -0.051080+0.018130j
9998  0.185130+0.009470j  0.113928+0.009426j

[9999 rows x 2 columns]
```

I don't know what `j` means above. Anyways, I wrote:

```
plt.xlabel('LD1')
plt.ylabel('LD2')
plt.scatter(
    X_lda.iloc[:,0],
    X_lda.iloc[:,1],
    c=1,
    cmap='rainbow')
```

but it throws:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py in _parse_scatter_color_args(c, edgecolors, kwargs, xshape, yshape, get_next_color_func)
   4262             try:  # First, does 'c' look suitable for value-mapping?
   4263                 c_array = np.asanyarray(c, dtype=float)
-> 4264                 n_elem = c_array.shape[0]
   4265                 if c_array.shape in [xshape, yshape]:
   4266                     c = np.ma.ravel(c_array)


IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Comment: ```j``` is the [immaginary part](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imaginary_number) of a complex number in python.

Comment: `y=1,2j` is a [complex number](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#complex). In python (for some reason) this is a built-in type. You need to call `y.real` or `y.imag` to get either `1` or `2`. In your case something like this might do it: `X_lda.iloc[:,0].map(lambda x: x.real)`

Comment: I cant help you with the problem but ' j ' is sometimes used instead of ' i ' to denote imaginary numbers

Comment: Usually in mathematics the real part is on the real axis or x axis and the imaginary part is on the imaginary axis or the y axis. not sure how you can use that for a scatter plot. Use just the real part instead?

Answer (score 0):

The colormap attribute `c` cannot be a single numeric sequence and `cmap` can only be used when `c` is an array of floats. I have replicated your dataset on a small scale. You may adapt this solution to solve yours.

```
X_lda = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.random.rand(5) + np.random.random(5) * 1j,
                      'b':np.random.rand(5) + np.random.random(5) * 1j})

# use as sequence for color mapping
cm = np.arange(5)
```

Then do this:

```
plt.xlabel('LD1')
plt.ylabel('LD2')
plt.scatter(
    X_lda.iloc[:,0],
    X_lda.iloc[:,1],
    c=cm, cmap='rainbow')
plt.show()
```

[image]