# How to adapt this python script to apt installed matplotlib vs pip3 installed

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

I have a script (MWE supplied)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib

s_xLocs = [864]
s_yLocs = [357]
s_score = [0.33915146615180547]
sMax = 0.34704810474264386
for i in range(len(s_xLocs)):
    plt.scatter(s_xLocs[i], s_yLocs[i],  c=s_score[i], s=(20*(s_score[i]+1.5)**4), cmap="plasma", marker='.', vmin=0, vmax=sMax)
matplotlib.pyplot.close()
```

which was being used to generate some plots using matplotlib. On my dev machine, I used matplotlib installed via `pip3`. The script is now being used on some other machines managed by IT and limited to using the version of matplotlib installed via `apt install python3-matplotlib`. This has caused my script to fail, throwing the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./heatmaps.py", line 9, in <module>
    plt.scatter(s_xLocs[i], s_yLocs[i],  c=s_score[i], s=(20*(s_score[i]+1.5)**4), cmap="plasma", marker='.', vmin=0, vmax=sMax)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2836, in scatter
    __ret = gca().scatter(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 1601, in inner
    return func(ax, *map(sanitize_sequence, args), **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 4451, in scatter
    self._parse_scatter_color_args(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 4264, in _parse_scatter_color_args
    n_elem = c_array.shape[0]
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

After reading [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59466371/tuple-index-out-of-range-in-scatter-plot) I was able to seemingly narrow down the issue to the colormap `c` argument. After also reading the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html) I also tried passing in the entire list of `s_score` with no indexing ala

```
plt.scatter(s_xLocs[i], s_yLocs[i],  c=s_score, s=(20*(s_score[i]+1.5)**4), cmap="plasma", marker='.', vmin=0, vmax=sMax)
```

but that gave a different and more confusing (IMO) error:

```
...
ValueError: Invalid RGBA argument: 0.33915146615180547
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
...
ValueError: 'c' argument has 1 elements, which is not acceptable for use with 'x' with size 1, 'y' with size 1.
```

I am hoping someone can provide a solution to this issue which will work with `python3-matplotlib` and perhaps also clarify the errors/what is different between the version installed with `pip3` vs `apt`.

Comment: Well, `c` is a param for color, and you are providing a float, when the value should be a string or a tuple with rgb color

Comment: @jjsantoso so if I want the color to be part of a color map dependant on that float score value, specifically the "plasma" color space, is there a different parameter that I would use in the apt installed version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be occasioned because of different versions of matplotlib installed.
As the problem is with the `c` parameter, I suggest creating a pallet and then getting the color based on the float value:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
import matplotlib as mpl

s_xLocs = [864]
s_yLocs = [357]
s_score = [0.33915146615180547]
sMax = 0.34704810474264386

palette = cm.get_cmap('plasma')
norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=0, vmax=sMax)

for i in range(len(s_xLocs)):
    color = palette(norm(s_score[i]))
    plt.scatter(s_xLocs[i], s_yLocs[i],  color=color, s=(20*(s_score[i]+1.5)**4), marker='.')
```

Comment: This is close to what I need, although there are 2 problems: 
-doing it this way causes the vmin/vmax arguments to be ignored and instead scale to 0-1.0, I am trying currently to find a way to fix this 
-when using a single RGB(A) value as in this case, `color` argument is to be used instead of `c` (it spit out a number of warnings about that when I ran with `c` arg)

Comment: You can create a norm to normalize values to a vmin & vmax. Look at the updated answer

Answer (score 1):

Another solution that did not break other functionality was to change plotting to this method:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib

s_xLocs = [864]
s_yLocs = [357]
s_score = [0.33915146615180547]
sMax = 0.34704810474264386
sSizes = [(20*(size+1.5)**4) for size in s_score]

plt.scatter(s_xLocs, s_yLocs,  c=s_score, s=sSizes, cmap="plasma", marker='.', vmin=0, vmax=sMax)
plt.show()
```